# Can I use sessions for a Flask-based REST API?

Tags: python, rest, flask, session

I was using Flask for a small personal project of mine, and using render template and simple HTML files for the front-end.

I recently decided to switch over to a react front-end with a REST API in Flask.
However, since a lot of my old flask code depended on using sessions within Flask, I was wondering if sessions can still be used with a REST API.

There are essentially two parts to the question:

1. Is it technically correct (i.e. would it even work)
2. Is it advisable (If no, why not)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use sessions for login for a front end API. For backend APIs I suppose you could as well but something like jwt or oauth2 is much more common for a few convenience reasons. Not sure the set cookie header works when called via the JS fetch api so you may need to create your own session cookie with JS and possibly in middleware. You also have the option of having the login page not part of the API which would solve this problem.

Other than that as long as the session cookie is being passed to the API every time it is called which should happen automatically you will be able to use sessions in your Flask code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
My question was regarding backend APIs specifically by the way. 
The answer definitely cleared up some stuff